# How to return an Object inside Javascript Event Listener?

Tags: javascript, events

I made a javascript event listener but i am not sure if i did not violate anything. This is how my code looks:

```
const url = window.location;
document.getElementById('save-employee-allowance').addEventListener('click', (e) =>{
    let allowance = document.getElementById('allowance').addEventListener('change', (e) =>{
        let item  = document.getElementById('allowance').value;
        if(item){
            let httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
            httpRequest.open('GET', url.origin+"/api/allowance/search/1/"+item);
            httpRequest.send();
            httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
                if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200){
                    if(typeof(JSON.parse(httpRequest.responseText).id) !== 'undefined'){
                        return JSON.parse(httpRequest.responseText);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
    console.log('Allowance Val >>> '+allowance);
});
```

and upon running, it gives me an undefined value for my allowance variable.
What should i do to return and get the value of my change listener?

Comment: You cannot do that.

Comment: I see. So i have to separate it.

Comment: Right, pass the decoded JSON to some function from *inside* the XHR callback.

Comment: Why would you add listener inside another one?

Comment: Not only does `addEventListener` not return the return value of the event handler, **it can't**, because: 1. When `addEventListener` returns, the event handler hasn't been called yet, and 2. The event handler will be called *every time* the event occurs, not just once. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/) linked questions' answers for details.